# Using gitk, can I see the difference between 2 commits?

Tags: git, gitk

I have tried:

```
git diff sha1 sha2
```

But the output isn't the best, is it possible to see the difference between 2 commits using gitk?

Answer (score 68):

In windows at least it is perfectly possible :

[image]

Comment: Worked for me with ubuntu too. This is a very good solution, I didn't know of this until now. Going to use this from now on, thanks!

Comment: how do you select multiple commits? I have tried CTRL clicking

Comment: @greenbrettmichael: I can't see a way to do this in gitk

Comment: You don't need to select multiple commits. Just click on one to select it then right mouse click over another commit you'll see the popup-menu as shown above.

Comment: Note that the right mouse click has to be on the commit comment, not a branch / tag name.  Right click on a branch / tag name gives you a different menu.

Comment: the option is appearing but disabled for me :(

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if you actually want a diff or if you want the normal gitk representation but only for the commits leading from `sha1` to `sha2`

In the later case you can provide all the normal revision parameters: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html

So you can do things like

```
gitk sha1..sha2
```

or if master got merged into the `sha2` branch and you don't want to see the commits that come from master and `sha1`, is the first commit branched from `master` use

```
gitk master..sha2
```

Comment: Same works for tags.  We tag all releases, and this way I can easily see all commit messages and related diffs between two released project versions.  If you know of some other neat ways to achieve this, please let me know =)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `gitk` doesn't support diff output in that way. :-(  You can use `git difftool` though.  It comes with support for a number of tools builtin.  For instance, you could do `git difftool -t kdiff3 sha1 sha2`.  It shows the file diffs one at a time.  There was talk on the git list about supporting more than just one file at a time via a diff tool, but I'm not sure where that ended up.  I haven't seen a patch implementing it yet.

Comment: Does that mean `gitk` can't use an external difftool? btw, you can use `git difftool -d sha1 sha2` to view directory differences now.

Comment: No, I don't believe so. :-(

Comment: I found that `gitk` supports `external diff` now, but it could only use the difftool to diff one file a time. And I'm sure that `git` now supports directory diff using the `git difftool -d sha1 sha2` command,  My git's version is `1.8.0` and I believe that this feature was implemented in version `1.7.11` or some other earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can do it using meld:

```
git checkout sha1
git reset sha2
git diftool --tool=meld
```

The trick is, by checking out sha1 and then resetting to sha2, you are making all the differences between them appear to be uncommitted changes. Then meld can use its ability to view uncommited changes, to do a diff of all the files involved at the same time.

Comment: I believe this is false. check answer by @Mr_and_Mrs_D